# QGridLayout vs QHBoxLayout & QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt, layout, gridview, widget

I have recently come back to Qt (tried it for previous projects and opted against it) and am really liking everything about it thus far. I am writing a TV Guide style application that will display Episode Guide Data (EPG) for anywhere from 3-7 days, and this data will be fed in from a Database source.

Right now I am having a hard time determining if I should use a QGridLayout or a combination of QHBoxLayouts (for the episode data) with a single QVBoxLayout on the left side (for the channel name/icons). My main concern with QGridLayout is that I would break it up into “30 minute” blocks, but when programs started at say 3:45, I am not sure it would work correctly. To give a better idea of what I am going for with the GUI, this screenshot can be viewed…

http://www.itvt.com/files/u3/AT&T-u-verse-tv-epg-2009.jpg

Just on a side note, if I want to only display a segment of this (i.e. 3:00AM – 4:30AM) and say 10 channels, which option would it be easier to implement vertical/horizontal scrolling with? Would I need to stick them in a different widget for that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QGridLayout.

Explanations:

With **QVBoxLayout and QHBoxLayout**, the number of column per rows is not fixed (or the inverse if you use these layout the other way), for example you can have something like:

```
|----------------------|
|------|------|--------|
|----------|-----------|
```

If you add an item to a row, the row will relayout without interfering with others, so column are not aligned anymore. It can be really convenient for some GUI, but for what you want I think it's not practical.

Then you have **QGridLayout**, *which is the way to go for your GUI*: all columns are aligned. So you can divide the grid in columns of 15 min, and then span widgets on several columns. Example:

```
0    15   30   45   60   75   90
|----|----|----|----|----|----| 6 x 15 min episodes
|---------|-------------------| 30 min + 1 hour episodes
|-----------------------------| 1h30 episode
|----|---------|---------|----| 2 x 15 min + 2 x 30 min episodes
```

Alignment is automatic.

*Note*: with QVBoxLayout and QHBoxLayout, the previous example would have been (without specific code):

```
0    15   30   45   60   75   90
|----|----|----|----|----|----|
|--------------|--------------|
|-----------------------------|
|------|-------|-------|------|
```

Notice how all cells in a row have the same size. This can be changed, but requires you to handle cell size manually...

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much for the diagrams as they helped to explain the scenario perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend QGridLayout because it will keep everything aligned easier than if you used a bunch of QBoxLayouts. With QGridLayout, your `addWidget` and `addLayout` methods have an optional `columnSpan` that you can make good use of. For example, you could have each column be 15 minutes, so a 45 minute show would span 3 columns.

You don't typically implement scrolling with QLayouts. I don't recommend it. Instead you can set QGridLayout's `rowMinimumHeight` and `rowMaximumHeight` to the same value so that you can ensure each row is the same height, then do the same for columns. Then you can put the layout (and encasing widget) into a QAbstractScrollArea and set the step size of the scroll bars to the row and column heights, so that as you scroll, it steps from channel to channel and time segment to time segment, rather than scrolling continuously.